# How many keys are too many in memcached?

Tags: memcached

I currently have about 650,000 items in memcached (430MB memory used) and the number is still increasing. It's expected to exceed 1,000,000 items before going flat. Current hit/miss ratio is 25:1 so the efficiency is pretty good. I just wanted to ask is one million items in memcached on single server too many? If not, how many is too many?

Comment: You can add another server and install memcache on it and distribute it. THat s the beauty of it, then you wont have to worry about this.

Comment: See? If memcached is good enough for server farms like the deathstar, it's good enough you.

Comment: Did someone stick a bounty on this *11 years* after the question was asked? True engineer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could scale *up* to a single 64-bit server with 48GB, and put up to 80,000,000 items in it.  Or you could scale *out* and buy many 4GB servers and put up to 2,400,000 items on each.  Memcached works wonderfully well when you distribute it across multiple servers.

Comment: @Jim, thanks for your answer, so 2,400,000 is the maximum number of items memcached can store in a 4GB box?

Comment: Sorry, that's a rough estimate based on your current 650k items in 430MB.  But 1m items is well under the max for such a machine.  You'll need to consider what happens as the *volume* of cache accesses goes up (does the CPU or the network become a bottleneck?) and also what happens if the memcached machine goes down. Even if a single machine could handle the cache and the load, you may need two or more to support failover for your application.

Comment: @JimFerrans I just came across this... https://memcached.org/blog/persistent-memory-2/ if the size of data held per item is less than 500bytes, I assume a 64GB server can hold up to 100million items without any significant performance difference..

Answer (score 2):

"Too many" is effectively however many you have when you run out of spare memory to dedicate to memcached.

The data is stored in a giant hash table, making lookups very close to O(1). As a hash table grows, collisions theoretically increase, but good quality (and suitable-for-memcached) implementations of the hash table concept generally include ample means to help deal with this with very little slowdown.

Comment: Aren't hash tables O(log(n))?

Comment: @user1130176 Not in the average case, no. O(log(n)) behavior from a putative hash table would suggest a broken or misapplied implementation. You may be thinking of some other structure also commonly used to implement associative arrays -- e.g. some form of tree.

Comment: The only way to get constant time would be some deterministic, one to one function from key to random access index, right, is that what memcached does? How could you traverse 100M records in in O(1) time?  I would love to learn how this is done.

Comment: @user1130176 Yes, that is how hash tables work, the key is put through a hash function, the output of which is an index into an array. I suggest reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for details.